How can I view all ESLint errors and warnings for my project in VS Code without opening each file individually?
I have a project with ESLint and the official ESLint extension for VS Code. There are numerous errors and warnings throughout the project.
When I open a file, VS Code displays only the errors and warnings related to that specific file. However, I want to see all the errors and warnings for the entire project without having to open each file one by one.
As shown in the image below, it indicates that there are 8 ESLint problems, but there are more issues in other files within the project that are not displayed here.
Is there a way to view all the errors and warnings for all the files in my project at once?


Run the linter on all your files in the terminal and you will get the listing you want.

You can try Error Lens vs-code extension.

It only shows the problems when I open the file in the code line, but I want to have a UI with a "summary" of problems from all files.

For summary, I think, eslint-formatter-summary This will be helpfull.

no. it's just terminal command. i looking a way to display in the UI of vscode all the problems from eslint like: file, error, file, error...
just like eslint does but for all the files with problems in the project.

You can generate error report in HTML format of individual file with command npx eslint -f html  path_to_file.tsx/jsx >  error.html.

but how to jump to the file at location? it's easier if its was on vscode and not external resource
